# Is there an adjectival form of the word "property"?

Tags: single-word-requests

To be precise, I am referring to the definition of property

*1. an attribute, quality, or characteristic of something.*

[[Oxford Languages, courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=property+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=dYy-ZMjVGYGPhbIP-L6UqAo&ved=0ahUKEwiI5OrVyKeAAxWBR0EAHXgfBaUQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=property+meaning&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEHByb3BlcnR5IG1lYW5pbmcyCBAAGIAEGLEDMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAESKMnUABYlyRwAHgAkAEAmAFvoAGACqoBBDE1LjG4AQPIAQD4AQHCAggQABiKBRiRAsICERAuGIAEGLEDGIMBGMcBGNEDwgIIEC4YgAQYsQPCAhEQLhiDARjHARixAxjRAxiABMICCxAAGIAEGLEDGIMBwgIFEC4YgATCAgcQABiKBRhDwgIOEAAYigUYsQMYgwEYyQPCAggQABiKBRiSA8ICDhAAGIAEGLEDGIMBGMkDwgIOEC4YigUYxwEY0QMYkQLCAhEQLhiKBRixAxjHARjRAxiRAsICCxAAGIAEGLEDGJIDwgINEC4YgAQYxwEY0QMYCsICBxAAGIAEGAriAwQYACBBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)]

and especially in referring to some physical object having a particular physical property like lustre or hardness.

Rules for adjective formation would suggest some word like "propertious" or "propertiful".

However, I have only found "propertied" but that seems to describe someone owning land. I am also considering "descriptive" but it seems too general to describe an object having some physical property. Of course, then property may be too general of a word to start with.

Anyways, are there lists of adjectives/(synonymous adjectives) for nouns like "property" which I could evaluate?

EDIT: An example sentence and discussion.

*The ____ importance of the object made it unique.*

I know I could say the "high quality of" or say the "important physical properties of" but it seems there is some missing adjective to describe the properties.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147438/discussion-on-question-by-sven-voigt-is-there-an-adjective-form-of-the-word-pro); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Your sample sentence seems inside-out.  It seems you want to say something like "That Voigtite offers property X and property Y and property Z makes it unique. No other alloy combines those three properties."   The having-multiple-desirable-properties property of Voigtite makes it unique.  In English we normally express something like that with a content-clause, "That it has ...."  or "The fact that it has..."

Comment: I have downvoted your question because the example sentence has the property of being too vague. You have been seeking a word that means "having a combination of properties that makes a thing unique".  How could that word modify **importance**?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a list anywhere, but people have made some good suggestions in the comments that could work. And by could work I mean that they would need to be defined in the text or be synonymous, since it doesn't appear there are actually adjective forms of property. Therefore, I am compiling a list to give some finality to the discussion.

Definable Words

- Propertied (John and Robbie)
- Proprietary (FumbleFingers)
- Empropertied (Not sure if a joke by Tim)
- Propertial (ermanen)

Synonyms of property as an adjective

- Attributive (FumbleFingers)
- Characteristic (Tinfoil Hat)

Comment: You can mention that _propertial_ is a neologism you can find in Google Books but it is not an established word. Some people have  neologized "propertal" also, for example.

Comment: You should edit this to mark it as community wiki.

Comment: By the way, your example sentence requires the adjectical form of "property" with the meaning  "of or relating to the properties (of something)", not "having a particular physical property", if one really wants to use. The suffixes _-al, -ial_ form adjectives with the former meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be seeking an adjective that means

> having some property

and nothing more (i.e. an adjective whose meaning does not in any way specify the property). The sense of *property* that is relevant to the question is the one in which it is synonymous with *quality*, not the one that has to do with ownership.

**There is no such word, because there is no need for it.** Every thing, in the broadest sense of *thing*, has some properties. Saying that a thing has some properties would thus never be informative. In other words, there are no things with no properties whatsoever, so we never need to tell anybody that a particular things has some. A thing without properties is a philosophical abstraction; nobody can ever encounter such a thing, because, as a matter of necessity, an encounter with a thing always involves some of its properties.

Moreover, if such a word did exist, it would not be suitable for use in the sample sentence that the OP provides at the end of the question. What is needed there is a word that explains what makes some object 'very unique'. The fact that something has some properties (as opposed to no properties), however, can never make it 'very unique'; in fact it puts it on a par with everything else. What may make a thing 'very unique' are the specific properties it has.

Comment: +1.  Exactly.......

Answer (score 0):

The **inherent** importance of the object made it unique.

**Inherent** (adj.) seems to describe an essential property:

OED

> **3.a. Existing in something as a permanent attribute or quality; forming an element, esp. a characteristic or essential element of
> something; belonging to the intrinsic nature of that which is spoken
> of; indwelling, intrinsic, essential.**
>
> 1855 There is some difficulty in ascertaining how much of the effect
> is derived and how much inherent. *A. Bain, Senses & Intellect
> Introduction ii. 52*
>
> 1886 Our inherent indolence, our apathy in times of peace is
> proverbial.
> *W. J. Tucker, Life Eastern Europe 33*

Answer (score -1):

**Proper** is the adjective from which **property** is derived. It means, in general, "belonging to".

Etymologically, **property** was simply the "state of that which is **proper**" to something, as *community* is the "state of that which is had in *common*".

> belonging characteristically to a species or individual : *peculiar* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proper)).

For example, a "proper name" or "proper noun" is a name *belonging to* someone or something.

> For "possessions, private property" Middle English sometimes used *proper goods.* ([etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/property))

It is said to be derived

> from Old French propre "own, particular; exact, neat, fitting, appropriate" (11c.) and directly from Latin proprius "one's own, particular to itself," from pro privo "for the individual, in particular," from ablative of privus "one's own, individual" (see private (adj.)) + pro "for" (see pro-). Related: Properly; properness. ([etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/proper))

**Proper** is sometimes used *after* the noun that it modifies. In the given example sentence, you could say:

> The importance **proper** of the object made it very unique.